# Trying to make a program that automatically sorts an array before using binary searching

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search, bubble-sort

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to input a set of 10 numbers before asking them to select a number from the list. it would first automatically sort the ten numbers before being placed in a binary searching function.

Here's the code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int searchbinary(int arr[], int left, int right, int x){
    while (left <= right){
        int mid = left+(right-left)/2;
        
        if (arr[mid]==x){
            return mid;
        }
        else if (arr[mid]<1){
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            right = mid -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main(){
    int num;
    int darr[10];
    int output;
    int temp;

    
    cout << "Enter 10 Numbers: " << endl;
    
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cin >> darr[i];
    }
    
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<10;j++){
            if (darr[i]>darr[j]){           
            temp = darr[i];
            darr[i] = darr[j];
            darr[j] = temp;
        }
        }
    }   
    
    
    cout << "Enter a number from list: ";
    
    cin >> num;
    
    output = searchbinary(darr, 0, 9, num);
    
    if (output ==-1){
        cout << "Match not Found";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Match Found in Position " << output;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

It works fine when I do it separately, but combining the two seems to cause an issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be more specific than "seems to cause an issue". What exactly does (or doesn't) happen that shouldn't (or should)?

Comment: Look at `if (arr[mid]<1)` and think about it for a while. (I suspect that you didn't use the same test data when it didn't work as when it did.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be a problem with your Binary Search. In the else if condition you wrote `arr[mid] < 1` whereas it should have been `arr[mid] < x` because you are trying to find x not 1. Bellow is the code that should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//binary search
int searchbinary(int arr[], int left, int right, int x){
    while (left <= right){
        int mid = (right+left)/2;//this formula is better than the one you used, it has the same results though
        
        if (arr[mid] == x){
            return mid;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] < x) {//here was your mistake,it is x not 1
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            right = mid -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main(){
    int num;
    int darr[10];
    int output;
    int temp;

    cout << "Enter 10 Numbers: " << endl;

    //input
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cin >> darr[i];
    }
    
    //sorting
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        for (int j=i+1;j<10;j++) {
            if (darr[i]>darr[j]) {
                temp = darr[i];
                darr[i] = darr[j];
                darr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Enter a number from list: ";
    
    cin >> num;
    
    output = searchbinary(darr, 0, 9, num);//searching
    
    //output
    if (output == -1){
        cout << "Match not Found";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Match Found in Position " << output;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

If you fix that issue then your code should work but I would like to point some things out:

1. It is better not to hardcode numbers, like when you write 10 as a limit to all for loops. It would be better to save 10 in a variable or use `darr.length()`.
2. Instead of using your own Sort you could have used the built-in sort that the algorithm library provides like this `sort(darr, darr+10)`. In this case it was only with 10 elements but bear in mind that if you ever find yourself trying to solve the same problem with array sizes up to a million or more, the sort you implemented(it is called [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)), would take up to much time, whereas std::sort would be able to do it faster as it has been optimised.
3. In this problem first sorting the array and then using Binary Search on top of it takes more time than performing [Linear Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) on the unsorted array. Generally, when searching once for a value on an unsorted array, first sorting it and then using Binary Search takes up more time than just doing Linear Search no matter the size of the array. However, if you wanted to to use the array in the future multiple times then your approach could prove to be faster.

These are all small improvements that you could make to your code but I am guessing this is done for educational purposes that is why you didn't do some of them.